# Entry instance has no attribute '__float__'

Tags: python

Im writing a simulation of firing a canon in python, i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\Skole\Dropbox\Skråkast\det_skraa_kast.py", line 47, in <module>
    float(speed)
AttributeError: Entry instance has no attribute '__float__'
```

My code (sorry for danish callnames :-):

```
#==LabelFrame==#

labelframe = LabelFrame(master, text="Parametre for affyring", bd = 3, font=("Aeria", "8", "bold"))
labelframe.pack(side = BOTTOM, expand="yes", fill="both")




#--Indtastning af fart--#

speedlabel = Label(labelframe, text="Indtast farten af kuglen", font=("Aeria", "8", "bold"))
speedlabel.pack(side = TOP)
speed = Entry(labelframe, bd = 3)
speed.pack(side = TOP)
float(speed)




#--Indtasning af vinkel--#

anglelabel = Label(labelframe, text="Indtast vinklen af kanonen", font=("Aeria", "8", "bold"))
anglelabel.pack(side = TOP)
angle = Entry(labelframe, bd = 3)
angle.pack()
float(angle)


... code creating a coordinate system ...




#==Update knap==#

def update(event=None):

        speedentry = speed.get()
        angleentry = angle.get()
```

Really hope you can help me :-)

Best regards, Casper

p.s Might be notable to say im running 2.7.3 (demanded by my teacher)

Comment: Why do you expect your `Entry` objects to be convertable to floats? What do you expect `float(speed)` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Entry` object is not cenvertible to `float`, but its value probably is. (I'm guessing you're using Tkinter.) Try this:

```
float(speed.get())

#...

float(angle.get())
```

Comment: I suspect the OP is expecting `float()` to do something else. Such as floating the label in the layout. Note that nothing is *done* with the output of `float()`.

Comment: I indeed suspected float() to convert it from a string, however your answer seemed to help me, thanks a lot! :-)